# How to call delegate methods of CollectionView inside TableView in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview, collectionview

TableViewCell Class

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
 //Registering CollectionViewCell
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [productsData count];
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"collectionCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSDictionary *cellData = [productsData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[cellData objectForKey:@"image"]];
    return cell;
}
```

How to call delegate methods of collection view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `TableViewCell.h` file add .

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) UICollectionView *yourCollectionView;
```

In your `TableViewCell.m` file add .

```
@synthesize yourCollectionView;
```

in your `init` method alloc collection view & set delegate & datasource .

```
yourCollectionView = [UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame://( your frame) ];

yourCollectionView.dataSource = self;
yourCollectionView.delegate = self;
// set other properties as per tour needs .

[self.contentView addSubview:yourCollectionView];
```

Add check your delegate methods wotrking fine . hope it helps you .

Comment: Its working but error is coming "must register a nib or a class for the identifier". So in the above code have i done proper coding for registering cell?

Comment: in your init method add  [yourCollectionView registerClass:[yourcollectionviewcellclass class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"indetifire"]; before allocating collection view.